# nextjs and React three Fiber TypeError: Failed to parse URL

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm working on a web game using React Three Fiber and Nextjs, I'm trying to load a model from my public folder, and I get this error even tho the model loads and appears in my scene. Note: I'm using ''use client'' in my code

The ERROR:

```
- error TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /Game_Assets/models/naturescene/naturescene.glb
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Game (./app/Game/page.tsx:49:86)
```

The Loader code:

```
  const naturemodel = useLoader(
    GLTFLoader,
    "/Game_Assets/models/naturescene/naturescene.glb"
  );
```

I tried using GLTFLoader but I still get the same problem